# Removing opacity and disabled property in Jquery not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a this code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Help</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="submitFxn" type="button">Submit</button>
    </body>

    <!-- Get ajax -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".submitFxn").on('click', function() {
                //change opacity and disable the button
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                $(this).css('opacity', 0.5);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost:8000/api/",
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },

                    data: {
                        params: "params"
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        //reset opacity and remove disabled prop
                        $(this).prop('disabled', false);
                        $(this).css('opacity', 1);
                        console.log("success");
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        //reset opacity and remove disabled prop
                        $(this).prop('disabled', false);
                        $(this).css('opacity', 1);
                        console.log("error");
                    },
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
<html>
```

which is a button that submits to an API, and after submission whether fail or success would clear the formatting of the button using jquery. But it is not working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign $(this) to a variable at the start. Then use that as your ref.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Help</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="submitFxn" type="button">Submit</button>
    </body>

    <!-- Get ajax -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".submitFxn").on('click', function() {
                //change opacity and disable the 

                //assign $(this) to var button
                var button = $(this);

                //use button var instead of $(this)
                button.prop('disabled', true);
                button.css('opacity', 0.5);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost:8000/api/",
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },

                    data: {
                        params: "params"
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        //reset opacity and remove disabled prop
                        button.prop('disabled', false);
                        button.css('opacity', 1);
                        console.log("success");
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        //reset opacity and remove disabled prop
                        button.prop('disabled', false);
                        button.css('opacity', 1);
                        console.log("error");
                    },
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
<html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because in your success or error callback , you are using function keyword. Due to this , when u call $(this) inside the callback function , it refers to callback function itself instead of your html element.

To fix this issue , you can use an arrow function instead.Arrow functions do not have their own execution context.And inside arrow function this is inherited from the parent function i.e this will refer to your html element.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Help</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="submitFxn" type="button">Submit</button>
    </body>

    <!-- Get ajax -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".submitFxn").on('click', function() {
                //change opacity and disable the button
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                $(this).css('opacity', 0.5);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost:8000/api/",
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },

                    data: {
                        params: "params"
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: (data)=> {
                        //reset opacity and remove disabled prop
                        $(this).prop('disabled', false);
                        $(this).css('opacity', 1);
                        console.log("success");
                    },
                    error: (err)=> {
                        //reset opacity and remove disabled prop
                        $(this).prop('disabled', false);
                        $(this).css('opacity', 1);
                        console.log("error");
                    },
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
<html>
```